# custom RL environment in pygame - question about define time step

Tags: python, pygame, reinforcement-learning

I'd like to make custom RL environment in pygame.
And, want to define decision timestep by the condition of environment(game)
(i.e. in case of shooting game, the timestep is when enemy's arrival)
how to make that kinds(inner condition of environment) timestep?
when using pygame?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get the number of milliseconds since [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) was called. The elapsed time can be used for the timestamp:

```py
timestamp = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```